# How put regex in getElementByIds

Tags: javascript

Suppose to have more buttons:

```
<input type="button" id="number_1" value="A">
<input type="button" id="number_2" value="B">

<input type="button" id="number_n" value="N">
```

I want get click when the user click on them. So I would use something like this code (without Jquery):

```
var button=document.getElementById('[id^=number]');
button.onclick=function(){alert("HIII")};
```

But this code is not work. Anyone can help?

Comment: It does not work because it does not support it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Attribute_selectors)

[document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

[Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

[Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

[EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id^=number_]'), function (element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   alert(e.target.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="number_1" value="A">
<input type="button" id="number_2" value="B">
<input type="button" id="number_n" value="N">
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> '[id^=number]'
> ```

That's an attribute selector, not an ID and not a regular expression. You shouldn't pass it to `getElementById`.

You can use selectors with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=number]');
```

but that returns a NodeList, not a single element, so you have to loop over it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    button.onclick=function(){alert("HIII")};
}
```

and there is no point in creating a new function each time you go around the loop, create one and reuse it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    button.onclick = myFunction;
}    

function myFunction () { 
    alert("HIII");
}
```